# How to change a state variable, calling self methods, and handling window functions while still using pure functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am currently looking into utilizing mostly pure functions in my code. I realize the benefits of this. However, I'm wondering what the best practice is when updating a state variable, calling methods defined within a module, and how to handle window functions.

Using the example below, let's say I have a module, `MyModule`.

- The `MyModule.calculate` function is pure, so no worries there.
- The `MyModule.trackSomething` function however is updating the `MyModule.count` to keep track of it for use in the event handler, used in `MyModule.assignEventHandlers` function. This is not pure because it is using an outside reference to a variable. Even if I refactor to make count an object and pass it in as a parameter to `MyModule.trackSomething`, I'd still be altering the value through reference, making it impure.
- In the `MyModule.assignEventHandlers` function, I'm using global window object functions. This makes it impure because I'm referencing outside functions. Should the window object be passed by reference when calling functions it has?
- In the `MyModule.init` function, I'm calling the `MyModule.assignEventHandlers` function. I guess this makes it impure as well since `MyModule.assignEventHandlers` is an outside reference.

So my question is: What is the best way to handle the last 3 bullet points?

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
const MyModule = {
    calculate(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },

    count: 0,

    trackSomething() {
        MyModule.count += 1;
    },

    assignEventHandlers() {
        // assign event handlers to some DOM elements
        window.document.getElementById('my-ele').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.alert(MyModule.count);
            MyModule.trackSomething(MyModule.count);
        });
    },

    init() {
        MyModule.assignEventHandlers();
    }
};
```

Comment: "*this makes it impure as well I'm referencing outside functions*" - no. It's because those outside functions are impure. Calling pure outside functions would be fine.

Comment: @Bergi So if assignEventHandlers was somehow adjusted to be pure, the init function would be considered pure as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think when we came out with a solution, instead of just focus on pure and impure function, it's better to focus on practicability as well. It's okay to have impure function.

Here is another version of the implementation using RxJs - a reactive js lib. Also using ES6 class instead of module. Take a look at `action` and `action2`. Both produce same result in different ways.

In my opinion, `action` is good enough. Don't need to make everything super pure.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(elementId) {
    this.ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.ele, 'click');
    this.count = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
  }
  
  calculate(a, b) {
     return a + b;
  }
  
  action() {
    window.alert(this.count.getValue());
    const nextVal = this.calculate(this.count.getValue(), 1);
    this.count.next(nextVal);
  }
  
  action2(log, subject, method) {
    log(subject.getValue());
    const nextVal = method(subject.getValue(), 1);
    subject.next(nextVal);
  }
}

const a = new MyClass('my-ele1');
a.click$.subscribe(() => a.action2(window.alert, a.count, a.calculate));

const b = new MyClass('my-ele2');
b.click$.subscribe(() => b.action());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="my-ele1">me1</button>
<br>
<button type="button" id="my-ele2">me2</button>
```